# PhotoEditor: Crafting Modern Cocoa Apps; Apple Sample code not compiling

Tags: swift, xcode8, macos-sierra

Has anyone successfully compiled the "PhotoEditor: Crafting Modern Cocoa Apps" sample app recently provided by Apple? I've managed to compile it after removing several private modifiers to instance variables but once running, it performs erratically. I filed a bug report with apple a week ago and haven't gotten a response. Their sample code is usually pretty good.